# change Startup form via a button in executed Program winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, exe, login-control

I have a program in C# Windows Form Application. The first form in my program is login form, if accept the user info via Login Form that Person guides to Main form.

In The Main form he can select an option button with name "Manage Login".

in manage Login, there is a button for disabling the Login form, my problem is how to disable Login form when my program compiled to exe file.

I think about in creating a table and with column in the name of "Check State" in my database and when disable Button clicked, save Check State="Disable" or again when clicking enable, the save Check State="Enable".

How can I check this state when at run-time.

Comment: show some code to understand the question better

Comment: @MohitShrivastava what did you edited !! I tried but got stuck in between & stopped editing :P

Comment: Hey @Nikita I have just updated the Hi Helloz and lot of dots OP has given in the question. Sorry for the interupption

Comment: @MohitShrivastava yeah, i get tht .. my problem was I did not know hw to continue editing ,so stopped..quite a lot things were missing, I lost the track!